# Is there a selector that can apply rules to only its children?

Tags: css

I have the below html:

```
<div class="widget1">
    <p class="rule1"></p>
    <p class="rule2"></p>
    <p class="rule3"></p>
</div>
<div class="widget2">
    <p class="rule1"></p>
    <p class="rule2"></p>
    <p class="rule3"></p>
</div>
```

I have the below rules:

```
.rule1 {
    color: red;
}
.rule2 {
    color: green;
}
.rule3 {
    color: blue;
}
```

I only want to apply these rules to widget1, NOT widget2.

**I know this works:**

```
widget1 .rule1 {
    color: red;
}
widget1 .rule2 {
    color: green;
}
widget1 .rule3 {
    color: blue;
}
```

However, I have like 30 rules that I want to apply to just widget1. Is there a selector that do something like this?

```
.widget1 {
    .rule1 {
        color: red;
    }
    .rule2 {
        color: green;
    }
    .rule3 {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

**Update:**

The whole purpose for seeking a good way to do that is to simplify the CSS and to avoid the overriding between different widgets with the same common rules (e.g. .rule1 .rule2 .rule3)

Comment: As far as I know, you can do that in a CSS preprocessor like SASS or LESS, but that will convert it to CSS and it will look like that too... So...

Comment: I would recommend combining common attributes into a rule and then assign several classes to each `p`  - i.e. `<p class='common rule1'>` and `<p class='common rule2'>` etc - this way you do not have to repeat yourself as much.  You can even create groups of common attributes (i.e. common1, common2) and combine them with the other rules.  You can add as many classes to `p` elements as you see fit

Answer (score 1):

I would create 'groups' of rules and add them to your elements as needed.

Something along the lines of

```css
/* all p elements as group */

.widget1 p {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
/* other elements (not necessarily a p) as a group */

.widget1 .common {
  min-height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
}
.widget1 .rule1 {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.widget1 .rule2 {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}
.widget1 .rule3 {
  width: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.widget1 .mute {
  color: grey;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="widget1">
  <p class="common rule1">1.1</p>
  <p class="common rule2 mute">1.2</p>
  <p class="common rule3">1.3</p>
  <div class="common rule1 mute">1.4 (notice no border here)</div>
</div>
<div class="widget2">
  <p class="rule1">2.1</p>
  <p class="rule2">2.2</p>
  <p class="rule3">2.3</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

**EDIT** after reading your question again.

You can use `p:nth-child(1)` see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rfb31uto/3/

```
.widget1 > p:nth-child(1) {
    background-color: red;
}
.widget1 > p:nth-child(2) {
    background-color: blue;
}
.widget1 > p:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Or this:

```
.widget1 > .rule1{
    background-color: red;
}
.widget1 > .rule2{
    background-color: blue;
}
.widget1 > .rule3{
    background-color: green;
}
```

Or This:

```
.widget1 > p:nth-child(3n+0){
    background-color: red;
}
.widget1 > p:nth-child(3n-2){
    background-color: blue;
}
.widget1 > p:nth-child(3n-1){
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: This solution would require the rules to be applied in a specific order but what if your first child is to have `.rule3`?  (ps I did not downvote)

Comment: Its ok, even if you did :) I am not here for the votes. And I don't think I understand what you are asking?

Comment: In your fiddle, how would you go about applying the same `rule` to elements 3, 4 and 6? As it stands, You would have to write the same rule three times with a different number (for each child).  But what if your elements changed order later on? your CSS would be incorrect...

Comment: Oh gatcha, a little math! BRB :)

Comment: Yes, closer to the second option... that way, if the `.green` element comes in first, second or tenth it would be applied correctly

Comment: @ochi I might be barking up the wrong tree all together but is this what you are saying? https://jsfiddle.net/rfb31uto/7/

Comment: Not really, no.  What I am saying is that your solution is tightly-coupled with the order of the elements.  Let's say you have the first and second paragraph styled exactly the same.  Your solution does not work.  Or if tomorrow the same first and second paragraph are edited and placed third and fourth, your solution will apply the wrong rule (because they no-longer are the first and second paragraphs)... Breaking the relationship between the order of the rule and the elements affected, allows you to move your paragraphs freely without having to re-write your CSS

Comment: I guess, you would be correct then lol, however OP did not state such requirements so I did not bother with the what if's

Comment: Well, the OP did say he had 30 rules (assuming multiple elements) and did not specify how many elements and which order.  Your solution is making those assumptions.  My comment is more related to the solution being so coupled with the order that it becomes less useful in other (most) situations

Comment: At this point, I will move on. It really does not matter all that much to me.